# Complex exponentiation is not well-defined?

Tags: complex-numbers, homotopy-theory

My topology teacher (in a lesson about the fundamental group of the circle) says that

$$F: S^1 \times [0, 1] \rightarrow S^1 \\ 
(z, t) \rightarrow z^{1+t}$$

is **not** an homotopy between $f(z) = z$ and $g(z) = z^2$ because F is **not well-defined** ($S^1$ here is seen as subset of $\mathbb C$).

Why? Complex exponentiation is not well-defined?

Intuitively I would do it writing the complex number in polar form $z = e^{i\theta}$ and evaluating $z^{t+1}= e^{i(t+1)\theta}$.
I suppose that the problem is that $\theta$ is not unique, but cannot we avoid this by choosing always angles $\in [0, 2\pi)$?

Comment: If you choose angles approaching $2\pi$ on one side of $0$ and angles approaching $0$ on the other side, your $\theta$ function is not continuous on $S^1$. $e^{i\theta}$ _is_ continuous, but then $e^{i\theta/2}$ is not. So when your prof said “not well-defined” I think he meant “not continuous”.

Comment: But is not $S^1$ obtained by identifying 0 and $2\pi$ ? It's not the function continuous with such topology? Sorry, I'm very confused

Comment: Yes, $S^1$ is obtained by identifying $0$ and $2\pi$. That is the very reason that a function on $S^1$ can only be continuous if it takes the same value near $0$ as it takes near $2\pi.$ Your proposed $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ does not do this. As a function on $S^1$ it has a jump discontinuity.

Comment: Of course! Thank you, I've now understand what you meant when you said that $e^{i\theta/2}$ is not continuos! Thank you

Comment: In general, there is no continuous square root function defined on the whole complex plane. There must be a branch cut. Similar remarks apply to any non integer power function.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to define exponentiation with arbitrary exponents is via logarithms, i.e., $a^b:=\exp(b\ln a)$. And in the complex case, we'd define the logarithm best as integral of the reciprocal function $z\mapsto \frac 1z$. As However, the result of this definition of $\ln $ is not well-defined in the sense that it depends on the region $\Omega$ we define it on. That region must be simply connected and not containing $0$ to allow our integration attempt to work. This way, different regions may produce different results. We speak of different *branches* of the logarithm. It turns out that complex logarithm is best be viewed as defined up to a multiple of $2\pi$ only. The same then applies to general exponentiation.

As said above, we can fix a branch consistently only if we are working on a simply connected region not containing $0$. In the problem, we want to define exponentiation on  $S^1$ which is *not* contained in such a region.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You said that the approach via logarithms is the best: why? It's not more natural to define it using classical power rule? (especially because complex numbers already are e-power)